# How to get the diagonal of a sparse matrix in cuSparse?

Tags: c++, cuda, cusparse

I have a sparse matrix in cuSparse and I want to extract the diagonal. I can't seem to find a way to do it other than converting it back to CPU memory into Eigen SparseMatrix and use the `.diagonal` provided by Eigen to do it, and then copy the result back to GPU. Obviously this is pretty inefficient so I am wondering if there's a way to do it directly in the GPU. Please see below code for reference:

```
void CuSparseTransposeToEigenSparse(
    const int *d_row,
    const int *d_col,
    const double *d_val,
    const int num_non0,
    const int mat_row,
    const int mat_col,
    Eigen::SparseMatrix<double> &mat){
  std::vector<int> outer(mat_col + 1);
  std::vector<int> inner(num_non0);
  std::vector<double> value(num_non0);

  cudaMemcpy(
      outer.data(), d_row, sizeof(int) * (mat_col + 1), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

  cudaMemcpy(
      inner.data(), d_col, sizeof(int) * num_non0, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

  cudaMemcpy(
      value.data(), d_val, sizeof(double) * num_non0, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

  Eigen::Map<Eigen::SparseMatrix<double>> mat_map(
      mat_row, mat_col, num_non0, outer.data(), inner.data(), value.data());

  mat = mat_map.eval();
}

int main(){

  int *d_A_row;
  int *d_A_col;
  double *d_A_val;
  int A_len;
  int num_A_non0;
  double *d_A_diag;

  // these values are filled with some computation

  // current solution
  Eigen::SparseMatrix<double> A;

  CuSparseTransposeToEigenSparse(
      d_A_row, d_A_col, d_A_val, num_A_non0, A_len, A_len, A);

  Eigen::VectorXd A_diag = A.diagonal();

  cudaMemcpy(d_A_diag, A_diag.data(), sizeof(double) * A_len, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

  // is there a way to fill in d_A_diag without copying back to CPU?

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: There isn't functionality to do that AFAIK, but it is trivial  to do. The solution would be format dependent

Comment: @talonmies what do you mean by format dependent? Can you please elaborate more?

Comment: Sparse matrices are no unicorns with magical properties. The rely on a pre-defined storage format. cuSparse supports about 5 different formats. Your matrix must be one of those. And how you extract the diagonal is different in each case. So the answer to the question depends on which format you are using

Comment: @talonmies The format I am using in cuSparse is CSR. Do I have to figure out writing a custom kernel to get it?

Comment: Yes, or something like a custom functor for thrust. As I said, it is trivial to do assuming you want a dense vector holding the diagonal -- make an array to hold the diagonal in GPU memory, have each thread find the diagonal entry in a row (if there is one) and put that value (or zero) in the correct place. 10 lines of code, max.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just in case anyone is interested. I figured it out for the case of a CSR matrix. The custom kernel to do it looks like this:

```
__global__ static void GetDiagFromSparseMat(const int *A_row,
                                            const int *A_col,
                                            const double *A_val,
                                            const int A_len,
                                            double *A_diag){
  const int x = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;

  if (x < A_len){
    const int num_non0_row = A_row[x + 1] - A_row[x];

    A_diag[x] = 0.0;

    for (int i = 0; i < num_non0_row; i++){
      if (A_col[i + A_row[x]] == x){
        A_diag[x] = A_val[i + A_row[x]];
        break;
      }
    }
  }
}
```